# jQuery gets table rows ids into array

Tags: jquery

I have the following table rows:

```
<tr><td id="-8">Test A</td></tr>
<tr><td id="-10">Test B</td></tr>
<tr><td id="-3">Test A</td></tr>
<tr><td id="-5">Test A</td></tr>
```

I need to get an array holding all the ids just if I did it manually

```
var data = []
data.push(-8);
data.push(-10);
data.push(-3);
data.push(-5);
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's easy. Use the `$("td").each()` and push the `id`.

```js
var data = [];
$('table td').each(function() {
  data.push(this.id);
});
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="-8">Test A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="-10">Test B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="-3">Test A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="-5">Test A</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

just select the elements and get the ids

```js
let data = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td')).map(({id}) => id);
console.log(data);
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td id="-8">Test A</td></tr>
<tr><td id="-10">Test B</td></tr>
<tr><td id="-3">Test A</td></tr>
<tr><td id="-5">Test A</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log($('td[id]').get().map(function(el) { return el.id; }));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td id="-8">Test A</td></tr>
  <tr><td id="-10">Test B</td></tr>
  <tr><td id="-3">Test A</td></tr>
  <tr><td id="-5">Test A</td></tr>
</table>
```

You would get all of the `td` elements with an `id`:

```
$('tr[id]')
```

and then use `.get()` to get the array of actual elements (not jQuery ones), and then `.map`:

```
$('td[id]').get().map(function(el) { return el.id; });
```

Comment: sorry, `this` should have been `el`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `map()`.

```js
var data = $('table td').map(function() {
  return +this.id; //+ to covert to number
}).get(); //get() to convert jQuery object to plain array

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="-8">Test A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="-10">Test B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="-3">Test A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="-5">Test A</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var id_arr = [];
$("body table tr td").each(function(){
    id_arr.push($(this).attr("id"));
});
```